# Firebird Duplicating items C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, firebird, firebird2.5

We have a Till Software which also works with restaurants built on .NET (C#) and Firebird DB. We are having a strange problem recently, the items in an order are duplicating themselves when we go back to the order.

Strangely it's not the case always. It's happening only sometimes. I tried to figure out under what conditions it's happening but it's so random that it doesn't happen for a couple of days and then start duplicating items for the next two days.

The software is so huge that I don't know what code snippets to even post. As it's not happening always and is random I guess it doesn't have to do with the code but with Firebird DB maybe.

The other thing I wanted to mention is that we had a Firebird DB built on a 32-bit machine and when we tried to put it on a 64 - bit machine it didn't work. So, we had to take a backup of the DB on a 32-bit machine and restore it on a 64-bit machine and it worked with the software. I'm thinking does that have something to do with it? but we have another user on 32-bit with no conversion and it's the same case for him as well.

I'll really appreciate any help or guidance on this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Till_Library.Till_Controls;
using Till_Library.Till_Interfaces;
using Till_Library.Till_Presenters;
using Till_Library.Till_Types;

namespace Till_Library.Till_Views
{
    public partial class viewOrderItems : UserControl
    {
        private IOrder mIOrder;
        private PresenterOrder mPresenterOrder;
        private readonly List<OrderGridItemRow> mOrderItemRowList;

        private OrderGridItemRow mCurrentItemRow;

        private readonly Color paidBckcolour = Color.GreenYellow;

        private decimal mTillMode;

        private readonly int ITEM_GRID_ROWS;
        private int mItemGridStartIdx;
        private int mItemGridEndIdx;
        private int mLastDisplayedRowIdx;
        private int mLastItemCount;

        private bool mSplitMode;
        public bool mIsRefund;
        private RestTable mCurrentTable;

        public delegate void TillCustDetailsClickedHandler();

        public delegate void TillOrderItemPhoneClickedHandler();

        public delegate void TillOrderTableSelectionClickedHandler();

        public delegate void TillOrderTableCoverClickedHandler();

        public delegate void TillOrderPriceClickedHandler(Point KeyPadLocation);

        public delegate void TillOrderQuantityClickedHandler(Point KeyPadLocation);

        public delegate void TillOrderItemClickedHandler(bool Option);

        public delegate void TillOrderCheckBoxClickedHandler(OrderItemDetails pOrderItemRow);

        public viewOrderItems(bool isRefund = false)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ITEM_GRID_ROWS = 11;
            mItemGridStartIdx = 0;
            mItemGridEndIdx = ITEM_GRID_ROWS;
            mIsRefund = isRefund;
            int CurY = 0;
            mIOrder = new IOrder();

            mOrderItemRowList = new List<OrderGridItemRow>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= ITEM_GRID_ROWS; i++)
            {
                CreateOrderItemRowControl(i, CurY);
                CurY += 36;
            }
        }

        private void CreateOrderItemRowControl(int pIdx, int pCurY)
        {
            string ItemRowName = "orderGridItemRow" + pIdx;
            mOrderItemRowList.Add(new OrderGridItemRow(pIdx));
            mOrderItemRowList[pIdx - 1].Name = ItemRowName;
            mOrderItemRowList[pIdx - 1].Location = new Point(4, pCurY);
            mOrderItemRowList[pIdx - 1].Parent = panItems;
            //OrderItemRowList[pIdx - 1].Parent = panel2;
            mOrderItemRowList[pIdx - 1].OrderItemClicked += TillOrderItemClicked;
            mOrderItemRowList[pIdx - 1].OrderItemPriceClicked += TillOrderItemPriceClicked;
            mOrderItemRowList[pIdx - 1].OrderItemPriceLeft += TillOrderItemPriceLeft;
            mOrderItemRowList[pIdx - 1].OrderItemQuantityClicked += TillOrderItemQuantityClicked;
            mOrderItemRowList[pIdx - 1].OrderCheckBoxClicked += OrderCheckboxClicked;
            mOrderItemRowList[pIdx - 1].Visible = true;
            mOrderItemRowList[pIdx - 1].SetOrderType(false);
            mOrderItemRowList[pIdx - 1].IsRefund(mIsRefund);
        }

        [Category("Action")]
        [Description("Cust Details clicked.")]
        public event TillCustDetailsClickedHandler TillCustDetailsClicked;

        protected virtual void OnCustDetailsClicked()
        {
            if (TillCustDetailsClicked != null)
            {
                //if(mTillMode != 3)
                TillCustDetailsClicked(); // Notify Subscribers
            }
        }

        public void AttachInterface(IOrder pIOrder)
        {
            mIOrder = pIOrder;
        }

        public void AttachPresenter(PresenterOrder pPresenter)
        {
            mPresenterOrder = pPresenter;
        }

        public void AttachOptions(IOptions pIOptions)
        {
        }

        public void AttachTableControl(RestTable pTable)
        {
            if (pTable != null)
            {
                mCurrentTable = pTable;
                labTableNo.Text = mCurrentTable.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                labTableNo.Text = "0";
                labTableCovers.Text = "0";
            }
        }

        public void SetTillMode(decimal pTillMode)
        {
            mTillMode = pTillMode;

            if (mTillMode == 2) // Restaurant Mode
            {
                labTableNo.Visible = true;
                labTableNoDesc.Visible = true;
                labTableCovers.Visible = true;
                labTableCoversDesc.Visible = true;
                labCustName.Visible = false;
                labCustNameTitle.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (mTillMode == 3) // Supermarket Mode
            {
                // This till mode also stops OnCustDetailsClicked() from firing

                labTableNo.Visible = false;
                labTableNoDesc.Visible = false;
                labTableCovers.Visible = false;
                labTableCoversDesc.Visible = false;

                labCustName.Visible = false;
                labCustNameTitle.Visible = false;

                panPhone.Visible = false;
            }
            else // Takeaway Mode (Default)
            {
                labTableNo.Visible = false;
                labTableNoDesc.Visible = false;
                labTableCovers.Visible = false;
                labTableCoversDesc.Visible = false;

                labCustName.Visible = true;
                labCustNameTitle.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        public ORDERTYPE GetOrderType()
        {
            return mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderType;
        }

        public void DisplayOrder(bool pRecall, bool pMoveToLast = false)
        {
            mPresenterOrder.AttachOrderView(this);
            mPresenterOrder.AttachOrderItemRowList(mOrderItemRowList);

           if (mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems.Count <= 11 && mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems.Count > mLastItemCount &&
                !pRecall && mTillMode == 3)
                mPresenterOrder.ProcessPanelDisplayBETA(false);
            else
                mPresenterOrder.ProcessPanelDisplay(false, pMoveToLast); // time waster

            mLastItemCount = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems.Count; // Accumulated Quantity Bug Fix & void ln

           // DisplayOrderDetails();
        }

        public void DisplayOrderDetails()
        {
            labOrderNo.Text = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderNo.ToString();
            labCustNo.Text = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderCustDetails.CustNo;
            labTableNo.Text = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderTableNo.ToString();
            labTableCovers.Text = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderTableCovers.ToString();
            labCustNameTitle.Visible = false;
            labCustName.Text = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderCustDetails.CustName;
            if (labCustName.Text != "")
            {
                labCustNameTitle.Visible = true;
            }

            //mPresenterOrder.UpdateTotals();
            //labDeliveryAmt.Text = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderDeliveryTotal.ToString("0.00");
            //labDiscountAmt.Text = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderDiscountPerc.ToString()+"%";         


            if (mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderDeliveryTotal > 0)
            {
                labDelivery.Text = "Delivery";
                labDelivery.Visible = true;
                labDeliveryAmt.Text = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderDeliveryTotal.ToString("0.00");
            }
            else if (mTillMode == 3 && mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderQty > 0 &&
                     mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderVAT == 0)
            {
                labDelivery.Text = "Item Qty";
                labDelivery.Visible = true;
                labDeliveryAmt.Text = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderQty.ToString();
            }
            else if (mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderVAT > 0)
            {
                labDelivery.Text = "VAT";
                labDelivery.Visible = true;
                labDeliveryAmt.Text = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderVAT.ToString("0.00");

                labDelivery.Font = new Font(labNetAmt.Font.FontFamily.Name, labNetAmt.Font.Size);
            }
            else
            {
                labDelivery.Visible = false;
                labDeliveryAmt.Text = string.Empty;
            }

            if (mTillMode == 3 && mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderQty > 0 && mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderVAT > 0)
            {
                labDiscount.Text = "Item Qty";
                labDiscount.Visible = true;
                labDiscountAmt.Text = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderQty.ToString();
            }
            else if (mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderDiscountAmt > 0)
            {
                labDiscount.Text = "Discount";
                labDiscount.Visible = true;
                labDiscountAmt.Text = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderDiscountAmt.ToString("0.00");
            }
            else
            {
                labDiscount.Visible = false;
                labDiscountAmt.Text = string.Empty;
            }

            double NetAmount = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderNET;
                // +mIOrder._mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderVAT;             

            if (mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OptionAddVATToPrice)
            {
                labNetAmt.Text = NetAmount.ToString("0.00");
                labTotalAmt.Text =
                    (NetAmount + +mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderVAT +
                     mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderDeliveryTotal - mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderDiscountAmt)
                        .ToString("0.00");
            }
            else
            {
                labNetAmt.Text = (NetAmount - mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderVAT).ToString("0.00");
                labTotalAmt.Text =
                    (NetAmount + mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderDeliveryTotal -
                     mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderDiscountAmt).ToString("0.00");
            }


            if (Convert.ToDouble(labTotalAmt.Text) < 0)
                labTotalAmt.Text = "0.00";

            CheckPaid();
        }

        public List<OrderGridItemRow> GetOrderItemRowList()
        {
            return mOrderItemRowList;
        }

        public IOrder GetIOrder()
        {
            return mIOrder;
        }

        public int GetPanelHeight()
        {
            return panItems.Height;
        }

        private void CheckPaid()
        {
            // RP Sets the total box to the local 'paidBckcolour' if the order displaied has been paid for, if not reverts back to default.
            if ((mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderPayment >= mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderTotal) &&
                mIOrder.mCurrentOrderDetails.OrderTotal != 0)
            {
                labDeliveryAmt.BackColor = paidBckcolour;
                labDiscountAmt.BackColor = paidBckcolour;
                labNetAmt.BackColor = paidBckcolour;
                labTotalAmt.BackColor = paidBckcolour;

                labDelivery.BackColor = paidBckcolour;
                labDiscount.BackColor = paidBckcolour;
                labNet.BackColor = paidBckcolour;
                labTotal.BackColor = paidBckcolour;
            }
            else
            {
                labDeliveryAmt.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                labDiscountAmt.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                labNetAmt.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                labTotalAmt.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

                labDelivery.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                labDiscount.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                labNet.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                labTotal.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            }
        }

         private void btnOrderItemGridUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO 
            bool bFirstItem = false;
            int OffsetIdx = 0;
            int OrderItemRowListCount = mOrderItemRowList.Count;

            if (OrderItemRowListCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < OrderItemRowListCount; i++)
                {
                    if (mOrderItemRowList[i].Top >= 0)
                    {
                        OffsetIdx = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            mItemGridEndIdx = mItemGridStartIdx + OffsetIdx;
            mItemGridStartIdx = mItemGridEndIdx - ITEM_GRID_ROWS;
            if (mItemGridStartIdx < 0 && mItemGridEndIdx < ITEM_GRID_ROWS &&
                (mItemGridStartIdx + mItemGridEndIdx + OffsetIdx < ITEM_GRID_ROWS))
            {
                bFirstItem = true;
                mItemGridEndIdx = ITEM_GRID_ROWS;
            }

            if (!bFirstItem)
            {
                int GridRowOffset = mOrderItemRowList[mLastDisplayedRowIdx].Bottom - panItems.Height;

                if (OrderItemRowListCount > 0 && GridRowOffset > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < OrderItemRowListCount; i++)
                    {
                        mOrderItemRowList[i].Location = new Point(1, mOrderItemRowList[i].Top - GridRowOffset);
                    }
                }
            }

            setItemGridIndex(mItemGridStartIdx, mItemGridEndIdx);
            mPresenterOrder.ProcessPanelDisplay(false);
            mLastDisplayedRowIdx = mPresenterOrder.mLastDisplayedRowIdx;
            mItemGridStartIdx = mPresenterOrder.mItemGridStartIdx;
            mItemGridEndIdx = mPresenterOrder.mItemGridEndIdx;
        }
        
        private void btnOrderItemGridDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int OffsetIdx = 0;
            int OrderItemListCount = mOrderItemRowList.Count;

            if (OrderItemListCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < OrderItemListCount; i++)
                {
                    if (mOrderItemRowList[i].Bottom > panItems.Height)
                    {
                        OffsetIdx = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (OffsetIdx == 0)
            {
                OffsetIdx = ITEM_GRID_ROWS;
            }

            if (mItemGridStartIdx + OffsetIdx <= mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems.Count)
            {
                mItemGridStartIdx += OffsetIdx;
                mItemGridEndIdx = mItemGridStartIdx + ITEM_GRID_ROWS;

                setItemGridIndex(mItemGridStartIdx, mItemGridEndIdx);

                mPresenterOrder.ProcessPanelDisplay(false);

                mLastDisplayedRowIdx = mPresenterOrder.mLastDisplayedRowIdx;
                mItemGridStartIdx = mPresenterOrder.mItemGridStartIdx;
                mItemGridEndIdx = mPresenterOrder.mItemGridEndIdx;
                //mPresenterOrder.DisplayOrderItems(mOrderItemRowList, panItems.Height);
            }
        }


        private void setItemGridIndex(int pStartIndex, int pEndIndex)
        {
            if (pStartIndex < 0)
                pStartIndex = 0;
            mPresenterOrder.mItemGridStartIdx = pStartIndex;
            mPresenterOrder.mItemGridEndIdx = pEndIndex;
            mPresenterOrder.mLastDisplayedRowIdx = mLastDisplayedRowIdx;
            // mLastDisplayedRowIdx = mPresenterOrder.mLastDisplayedRowIdx;
        }

        public void setSplitMode(bool pMode)
        {
            mSplitMode = pMode;
        }

        private void labCustNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnCustDetailsClicked();
        }

        private void labCustNoDesc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnCustDetailsClicked();
        }

        private void labCustName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnCustDetailsClicked();
        }

        private void labCustNameTitle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnCustDetailsClicked();
        }

        private void labOrderNoDesc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnCustDetailsClicked();
        }

        private void labOrderNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnCustDetailsClicked();
        }

        private void panCustInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnCustDetailsClicked();
        }

        public void TillMark2PrintClicked()
        {
            if (mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems.Count > 0 && mCurrentItemRow != null)
            {
                mCurrentItemRow.SetMark2PrintOrderSelected(true);

                foreach (TillOrderItem item in mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems)
                    if (item.GetItemID() == mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItemID)
                        if (!item.GetMarked2Print())
                            item.SetMark2Print(true);
                        else
                            item.SetMark2Print(false);
            }
        }

        public void TillMark2PrintReset()
        {
            foreach (TillOrderItem item in mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems)
                item.SetMark2Print(false);
        }

        [Category("Action")]
        [Description("Order Item Price Clicked.")]
        public event TillOrderPriceClickedHandler TillOrderPriceClicked;

        protected virtual void OnTillOrderPriceClicked(Point pKeyPadLoc)
        {
            if (TillOrderPriceClicked != null)
            {
                TillOrderPriceClicked(pKeyPadLoc); // Notify Subscribers
            }
        }

        private void TillOrderItemPriceClicked(OrderGridItemRow pOrderItemRow)
        {
            OnTillOrderPriceClicked(GetRowLocation(pOrderItemRow));
        }

        private Point GetRowLocation(OrderGridItemRow pOrderItemRow)
        {
            int mKeyPadX, mKeyPadY;

            Point mFloutingKeypadLoc;

            mCurrentItemRow = pOrderItemRow;

            mKeyPadX = pOrderItemRow.Location.X + pOrderItemRow.Width + 2;
            mKeyPadY = pOrderItemRow.Parent.Location.Y + pOrderItemRow.Location.Y + (pOrderItemRow.Height/2);

            mPresenterOrder.ClearOrderItemGridSelections(false);
            mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItemID = mCurrentItemRow.ItemID;

            mFloutingKeypadLoc = new Point(mKeyPadX, mKeyPadY);

            return mFloutingKeypadLoc;
        }

        private bool TillOrderItemPriceLeft(double pNewItemPrice, double pOldItemPrice)
        {
            if (pOldItemPrice >= 0)
            {
                if (pNewItemPrice >= 0)
                {
                    if (SetTillItemPrice(pNewItemPrice))
                        return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (pNewItemPrice < 0)
                {
                    if (SetTillItemPrice(pNewItemPrice))
                        return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private bool SetTillItemPrice(double pNewItemPrice)
        {
            foreach (TillOrderItem Item in mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems)
            {
                if (Item.GetItemID() == mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItemID)
                {
                    Item.SetItemPrice(pNewItemPrice);
                    mPresenterOrder.UpdateTotals();
                    DisplayOrder(false);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        [Category("Action")]
        [Description("Order Item Quantity Clicked.")]
        public event TillOrderQuantityClickedHandler TillOrderQuantityClicked;

        protected virtual void OnTillOrderQuantityClicked(Point pKeyPadLoc)
        {
            if (TillOrderQuantityClicked != null)
            {
                TillOrderQuantityClicked(pKeyPadLoc); // Notify Subscribers
            }
        }

        private void TillOrderItemQuantityClicked(OrderGridItemRow pOrderItemRow)
        {
            OnTillOrderQuantityClicked(GetRowLocation(pOrderItemRow));
        }

        public void SetItemQty()
        {
            mCurrentItemRow.RefreshItemRow();

            if (mCurrentItemRow.ItemQty == 0)
                mCurrentItemRow.ItemQty = 1;

            mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems[
                mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems.FindIndex(i => i.GetItemID() == mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItemID)].SetItemQty(
                    (int) mCurrentItemRow.ItemQty);

            mPresenterOrder.UpdateTotals();
            DisplayOrder(false);
        }

        private void TillOrderItemClicked(OrderGridItemRow pOrderItemRow)
        {
            mCurrentItemRow = pOrderItemRow;
            mPresenterOrder.ClearOrderItemGridSelections(false);
            mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItemID = pOrderItemRow.ItemID;

            if (mSplitMode)
            {
                mPresenterOrder.SetAsSplitItem(mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItemID);
                DisplayOrder(false);
                mPresenterOrder.ProcessPanelDisplay(mSplitMode);
                //mPresenterOrder.ProcessPanelDisplay(!mSplitMode);
            }
            else
            {
                mCurrentItemRow.SetOrderItemSelected(true);
                ShowItemControls(true);

                //  viewfunc
            }
        }

        public void UpdatePhone()
        {
            if ((string) picPhone1.Tag == "1")
            {
                picPhone1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.phone_ringing;
                panPhone.BackColor = Color.White;
                picPhone1.Tag = "2";
            }
            else
            {
                picPhone1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.phone1;
                //picPhone1.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
                panPhone.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(114, 205, 206);
                picPhone1.Tag = "1";
            }
        }

        [Category("Action")]
        [Description("Order Item Phone Clicked.")]
        public event TillOrderItemPhoneClickedHandler TillOrderItemPhoneClicked;

        protected virtual void OnOrderItemPhoneClicked()
        {
            if (TillOrderItemPhoneClicked != null)
            {
                TillOrderItemPhoneClicked(); // Notify Subscribers
            }
        }

        private void picPhone1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnOrderItemPhoneClicked();
        }

        public void ResetPhone()
        {
            picPhone1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.phone1;
            panPhone.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            picPhone1.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            picPhone1.Tag = "1";
        }

        public int getCurrentTableNo()
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(labTableNo.Text);
        }


        [Category("Action")]
        [Description("Order Item Clicked, Show Controls")]
        public event TillOrderItemClickedHandler TillShowControls;

        protected virtual void OnTillShowControls(bool pOption)
        {
            if (TillShowControls != null)
            {
                TillShowControls(true); // Notify Subscribers
            }
        }

        private void OrderCheckboxClicked(OrderItemDetails pOrderItemRow)
        {
            OnOrderChecked(pOrderItemRow);
        }

        [Category("Action")]
        [Description("Order Checkbox Clicked")]
        public event TillOrderCheckBoxClickedHandler OrderChecked;

        protected virtual void OnOrderChecked(OrderItemDetails pOrderItemRow)
        {
            if(OrderChecked != null)
            {
                OrderChecked(pOrderItemRow);
            }
        }

        private void ShowItemControls(bool pOption)
        {
            OnTillShowControls(pOption);
        }


        [Category("Action")]
        [Description("Assign Order to Table Clicked.")]
        public event TillOrderTableSelectionClickedHandler TillOrderTableSelectionClicked;

        protected virtual void OnTillOrderTableSelectionClicked()
        {
            if (TillOrderTableSelectionClicked != null)
            {
                TillOrderTableSelectionClicked(); // Notify Subscribers
            }
        }

        private void panTableSel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Table Selections
            Console.Write("Table Selection");
            OnTillOrderTableSelectionClicked();
        }

        private void labTableNoDesc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write("Table Selection");
            OnTillOrderTableSelectionClicked();
        }

        private void labTableNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write("Table Selection");
            OnTillOrderTableSelectionClicked();
        }

        [Category("Action")]
        [Description("Assign Customers to Table Clicked.")]
        public event TillOrderTableCoverClickedHandler TillOrderTableCoverClicked;

        protected virtual void OnTillOrderTableCoverClicked()
        {
            if (TillOrderTableCoverClicked != null)
            {
                TillOrderTableCoverClicked(); // Notify Subscribers
            }
        }

        private void panTableCov_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // No of People on Table, Selections
            Console.Write("Table Covers");
            OnTillOrderTableCoverClicked();
        }

        private void labTableCoversDesc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write("Table Covers");
            OnTillOrderTableCoverClicked();
        }

        private void labTableCovers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write("Table Covers");
            OnTillOrderTableCoverClicked();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "machine it didn't work" - this has no information in it. https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Comment: in general staring with FB2.5 you can use tools like FBprofiler or IBExpert TraceAPI menu to intercept almost all exchanges between your program and your database. Dunno if it would help though, since you can not reproduce the error. `fb_trace_mgr` program is part of Firebird, it might be easier burden on the computer than GUI tools ,if you would dare to keep it running long-term. At least you may try to log the same short and exactly repeated actions in your program in "good days" and "bad days". There would be some noise but perhaps some meaningful difference too. Or not.

Comment: The code you quoted does not seem to have any database interaction at all. Also it is unclear if you have copyrights on the code and can publish it at all....

Comment: Find the part of the program that gets executed "when we go back to the order" (whatever that means) and *trace* it into makinfg reading from the database. Also it is unclear if the rows are duplicated only on screen or if they are recorded duplicated into the database. Is it wrong interpretation of correct data or is the data tampered too. All in all it seems you occasionally populate some container without clearing it first. Just a random guess though. If so, then fix would be either to avoid re-population or to clear before re-reading. Consult the software programmer which was their design

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of the [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64752415/how-to-stop-firebird-from-duplicating-items) asked under the account Akram Hussain, except this time posted with a lot of code that does not seem to be [mre]. If you have nothing to pinpoint the problem, we can't really help you. The problem is unlikely to be in Firebird itself (randomly duplicating items would be a bad thing for a database engine), so you need to debug your code to pinpoint exactly when it happens, and then reduce the code to a [mre].